# Error: No se puede realizar enlace en tiempo de ejecución en una referencia NULL

Tags: c#, objeto

Tengo la siguiente situación:

Estoy usando un proyecto c# con **entity framework**. Cargo una tabla de impuestos dentro de un *ViewBag* en el *Index* de la vista con:

```
ViewBag.Impuestos = db.Impuestos.Where(i => i.Activo == true).ToList();
```

En la vista intento asignar los valores en un select, La variable trae 3 valores, el for recorre los 3 sin problema pero intenta un cuarto recorrido y se cae,Reviso bien y Todos los datos vienen pero aquí me da el error de:  **No se puede realizar enlace en tiempo de ejecución en una referencia NULL.**

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException:

```
 <select id="CodImpuesto" name="CodImpuesto" class="form-control slCodImpuesto">
                            <option value=""> -- Seleccionar -- </option>
                            
                            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Impuestos)
                                {
                                    <option value="@item.HaciendaCodigo"
                                            data-tarifa="@item.HaciendaCodigo">
                                        @item.Nombre
                                    </option>

                                }
                        </select>
```

Datos de la variable Impuestos
[image: Valores del indice 0]
[image: Valores del indice 1]
[image: Valores del Indice 2]

He intentado de todo, incluso hacer un `for (int i = 0; i <= ViewBag.Impuestos.Count - 1; i++)`
Igual error de **NULL**.

En la vista tengo otras cargas similares y si funcionan bien. Ya no se que revisar o que hacerle para que me cargue los datos.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: pues como dices, parece que tu código esta correcto, lo único que te puedo decir es que coloques un punto de parada (F9) y vayas depurando, comprueba que cada iteración obtiene correctamente los datos, tal vez no tenga acceso e item siempre sea null

Comment: He intentado eso que mencionas, el For pasa bien por lo 3 valores y  ninguno es Null, despues del tercer recorrido se cae como queriendo hacer un cuarto recorrido.

La aplicación la estoy migrando para cambiarle el aspecto gráfico, si pongo la vista vieja con las mismas instrucciones, esta si carga los datos bien.

Incluso intente Recreando la tabla en la base de datos y reasignando todos los valores de los campos. Y nada me ha servido.

Comment: me parece raro que teniendo 3 valores y realizando un foreach te trate de realizar 4 iteraciones, cuando se lo asignas al viewbag has depurado ahi?

Comment: Estuve leyendo y en algunos lados a personas con tu mismo error, les pasaba que el error estaba en otro lado y que lo marcaba (incorrectamente) en otro punto que si estaba correcto

Comment: ¿Qué te parece si armas un `Model` para esa vista?

Comment: Si he depurado cuando asigna el ViewBag y siempre van los 3 registros con todos los datos antes de hacer el return del view

La vista carga de la misma forma otros valores como clientes, productos, etc.

Incluso si le pongo un try, igual da el error y se cae.
Intente tambien sacando los datos con un Query: ( ViewBag.Impuestos = db.Database.SqlQuery<Impuestos>("Select * From Impuestos Where Activo=1").ToList();)

y e la vista : for (int i = 0; i <= ViewBag.Impuestos.Count - 1; i++)

Tengo mucho codigo igual y solo este me falla.

Comment: Ya pude localizarlo, el error estaba mas abajo en parámetros que No venían, me recordó a Cobol que te daba un error en la línea 100 y el problema real andaba por otro lado.

La confusión la hace el compilador que te marca un lugar incorrecto.

Gracias